# pinterest SDK for iOS missing pin description

Tags: ios, pinterest

I'm using pinterest SDK on my iOS app.
code example:

```
    [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageData.url]
     sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/pinterest.html?al_applink_data=type%%3Dimage%%26id%%3D%@",APPLINKS_LINK, self.imageData._id]]
                        description:@"blabla"];
```

For some reason the description is missing when I switch to the pinterest app.
(the URL is working - don't go there... :))
Anyone has an idea/encountered it?

Comment: Try [decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359851/decompile-obj-c-framework) iOS Library and see the code... or look up [Possible documentation for HTTP Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation)

Comment: Are you setting a valid pinterest ID

Comment: @Vishnu - yes. The pins are created with the correct image and URL only without the text

Answer (score 1):

Well. Apparently it was a bug in the specific version of Pinterest app for iOS. Was fixed on 21/8. Too bad their support took 2 weeks to get back to me with this answer :(